# How to get dependecies from package.json for creating logical tree of the project?

Tags: javascript, json, node-modules

The goal of this question.We have many different projects, and it is often difficult and long to analyze the dependencies of each project.
 Therefore, when developers, or the team gets a new project for them - they study for a long time, and investigate what is in dependence, etc.
I want to make a solution: use something like npm ls command.

In general, this command builds the dependency tree of the project,
our goal is to give a solution to the type npm ls, but it should be:
- be able to filter dependencies using a regular expression entered by the user
For example, i want to get result something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH7W0.jpg)
I want to type something like this  {path to the project} {expression for packet filtering} 
I want to take the code npmls an create the function that check all dependecies in package.json and as a result print the object of dependecies.

Comment: Your question is highly unclear. You need to better explain what you want to do.

Comment: I need to implement function something like npm-ls , this is must be a script..that can help me to select depencies what i need. When i start npm -ls this comand create to much depencies . i need to get a result something like that  package-tree ./(1)package.json -o ../(2)report.html
↑ analog «npm ls»
where 1 -is what i need  and 2 where to put this dependencies

Answer (score 0):

> implement using the typescript command npm-ls or how to pull this ls function from npm with minimal cost?

You can use child_process.spawnSync(command[, args][, options]) : https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
const output = child_process.spawnSync('npm', ['ls']);
```

## More

- Use `@types/node` for this
- Prefer the raw `spawn`. This is just a quick example with `spawnSync`.